# Concat each element of list with each element of second list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have two lists `['_ru', '_uk', '_en'], ['1','2','3']`

How I can get

```
['1_ru', '1_uk', '1_en', '2_ru', '2_uk', '2_en', '3_ru', '3_uk', '3_en']
```

in one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the cartesian product of two lists and join them, like this

```
>>> l2, l1 = ['_ru', '_uk', '_en'], ['1','2','3']
>>> from itertools import product
>>> ["".join(items) for items in product(l1, l2)]
['1_ru', '1_uk', '1_en', '2_ru', '2_uk', '2_en', '3_ru', '3_uk', '3_en']
```

Or in one line, with list comprehension

```
>>> ["{}{}".format(i1, i2) for i1 in l1 for i2 in l2]
['1_ru', '1_uk', '1_en', '2_ru', '2_uk', '2_en', '3_ru', '3_uk', '3_en']
```

This is basically the same as iterating the second list for each item in the first list and accumulating the result, like this

```
>>> result = []
>>> for i1 in l1:
...     for i2 in l2:
...         result.append("{}{}".format(i1, i2))
>>> result
['1_ru', '1_uk', '1_en', '2_ru', '2_uk', '2_en', '3_ru', '3_uk', '3_en']
```